# Enviar array a otro componente Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

tengo la siguiente pregunta. Como puedo enviar los datos de un array que obtengo en un componente a otro?
Este es el array que obtengo en el componente detalle:

```
props: {
        provider: {
            type: Provider,
            required: true
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.load()
    },
    methods: {
        async load() {
            const uid = this.$route.params.id
            this.provider.specialities //Este es el array que necesito enviar en la variable "currentarticle"
            
        }
    }
```

Este array necesito utilizarlo en esta funcion del componente lista

```
    created () {
        this.loadAds()
      },
      methods: {
        async loadAds() {
          try {
            const adSpecs = {
               "getcurrentarticle": this.currentarticle //los datos del array necesito utilizarlos aqui
            }
            this.ads = await AdsApi.loadAds(adSpecs)
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
          } finally {
            this.loading = false
          }
        },
     }
```

La idea es que cada vez que se detecte cambios en la variable "currentarticle" se llame a la funcion de arriba con el watch:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('Articles', ['currentarticle']),
    },
watch: {
   currentarticle (newVal) {
      if (newVal.length > 0) {
        this.loadAds(newVal)
      }
   }
}
```

De que forma puedo enviar los datos del array para que se detecten los cambios? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por que no por una `prop`? Veo que ya estás utilizando una prop en el componente "padre", puedes hacer lo mismo para pasarle el array al componente hijo

Comment: Si el "otro" componente no es hijo del que tiene el array, también veo que estás usando vuex, así que podrías puner el array ahí y obtenerlo desde cualquier componente de tu aplicación